# Why does implementation of onPurchasesUpdated() result in ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED and an empty purchases list?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm currently implementing in-app purchases for virtual coins that are consumable.

I'm using an internal test track and my test account is connected.

Launch billing flow is initiated by a button.

However there are a few issues.

#### The purchase list is null, which I don't believe is normal.

```
@Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {


        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {

            for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                handlePurchase(purchase);
            }

        } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {

        } else {

        }
```

The if statement will not run.

If I try to force test handlePurchases()'s functionality by passing this snippet to the else statement in onPurchasesUpdated(), it will result in a null object reference error because its trying to iterate through an empty list.

```
for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                handlePurchase(purchase);
            }
```

#### BillingResult code returns: ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED

To fix this I tried to call consumeAsync(), as shown in the code below.

```
    public void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            // Grant entitlement to the user.

            ConsumeParams consumeParams =
                    ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                            .build();

            client.consumeAsync(consumeParams, consumeResponseListener);


        }
    }
```

Additionally, I refunded all of the the existing orders in the Play Consoles' order management.

My question is why the ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED error still remains, and why the purchases list is empty.